# Upcast a POJO to a JPA Entity Class

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Consider an `@Entity` class `A`, and another class `B` that is a POJO and extends `A`.

Is there any way to force an upcast of `B` to `A` (Without Reflection)?

I have a method that receive an object of class `A` and persist that object. 
Passing a reference to an object `B`, will cause JPA to fail because it still consider the object as an instance of class `B`, and `B` is not annotated with `@Entity`.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the `@Inheritance` annotation which allow inheritance relationships in object models, it can be setup in a number of ways (table per class, single table).

I have created video tutorials detailing these two strategies.  The first video covers the [single table strategy](http://blog-tothought.rhcloud.com/post/21) and the other covers [table per class](http://blog-tothought.rhcloud.com/post/22).

Using the single table strategy you would annotate class A as follows:

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@Table(name="TABLE_NAME")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="DISCRIMINATOR_COLUMN", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@Entity
public class A {}
```

Then annotate class B:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_NAME")
@DiscriminatorValue(value="VALUE_TO_DISTINGUISH_B")
public class B{}
```

One thing to note is that in this case `B` is made an entity, which I believe will be required in any scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do not want/can not add the `B` entity to the persistence.xml file. If so, you could use Jackson like this:

1.Create `B`'s JSON representation:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(instanceB);
```

2.Create an `A`-instance from the JSON String, ignoring the unknown properties. Use [this setting](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.6.0/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/annotate/JsonIgnoreProperties.html) for that.